# Files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, linker

I am using a very common lib (Qt) under Ubuntu and the compilation fails telling me it cannot find functions which I do know are in the lib.

Now it turns out an old version of this lib is pre-installed in the root by Ubuntu side-by-side with the version I use in my dependencies.

And looking at the CMake messages I get the error message ***files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories***.

I have let the lib know where to look for using ***set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${QT_DIR})*** before calling ***find_package()*** but this did not work.

Any genius knows what I should do?

Comment: The message "Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target ..." is a WARNING, not an error. However, it signals that things will likely go wrong. Even if you resolve compilation error (probably, `include_directories(BEFORE <new-qt-include-dir>)` will help), and successfully build the program, **running the program** will get errors or wrong behavior, because the library from the implicit directory will be loaded. Either remove old QT or build the project against it instead of the new one.